# Javascript function run after CSS paint is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, stylesheet

I am using javascript to load my CSS files. I want to run a function once all CSS files have been downloaded and painted.

I do have jQuery loaded so I can use one of its functions.

.ready and .load don't seem to be waiting for CSS to complete the paint.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I couldn't find the link. Can you please list where it has been answered? I see a lot of questions answering how to wait for load but not specifically for CSS paint wait. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go for this :

//Checks if to.css and to1.css are loaded or not.

```
if ($("link[href='/path/to.css']").length && $("link[href='/path/to1.css']").length )
{
   //Function after above 2 CSS are loaded.
}
```

Comment: I tried the method, but it still keeps waiting before painting the CSS.